# Database insertion within a foreach loop while still calling in different functions in the sequence

Tags: php, ajax

I have a bit of a bug, and I can't tell where the error comes from.

I am building a cart system that will insert multiple data to a database from a cart on submit.

I'm using AJAX for this and I'm have errors, please I need help.

Here are my code snippets:

**JavaScript Code**

```
function addSale(payment_type, cash_tendered) {
var cust_name = $("#cust_name").val();
var amt_owed = $("#amt_owed").val();

$.confirm({
    title: 'Checkout',
    content: '' +
            '<form action="" class="formName" role="form">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<label>Payment Type</label>' +
            '<select id="eType" class="name form-control">' +
            '<option value="cash">Cash</option>' +
            '<option value="card">Card</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<label>Cash Tendered</label>' +
            '<input type="number" id="eCash" placeholder="Cash Tendered" class="name form-control">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</form>',
    buttons: {
        cancel: function () {
            //close
        },
        formSubmit: {
            text: 'Checkout',
            btnClass: 'btn-success',
            action: function () {
                payment_type = this.$content.find('#eType').val();
                cash_tendered = this.$content.find('#eCash').val();


                if (!payment_type || !cash_tendered) {
                    $.alert('Please fill all fields.');
                    return false;
                }

                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Do you want to continue?',
                    type: 'orange',
                    content: 'Click Ok to add sale',
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: function () {
                        },
                        proceed: {
                            text: 'Ok',
                            btnClass: 'btn btn-success',
                            action: function () {
                                var addUrl = "home/addsales";
                                addUrl += "/" + payment_type;
                                addUrl += "/" + cash_tendered;
                                addUrl += "/" + cust_name;
                                addUrl += "/" + amt_owed;

                                //
                                $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: addUrl, data: {},
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        $.alert({
                                            content: result
                                        });
                                        $("#eType").val("");
                                        $("#eCash").val("");
                                        $("#cust_name").val("");
                                        $("#amt_owed").val("");
                                        location.reload();
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                                        $.alert({
                                            content: 'Could not complete the process. ' + error
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    onContentReady: function () {
        // bind to events
        var jc = this;
        this.$content.find('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            // if the user submits the form by pressing enter in the field.
            e.preventDefault();
            jc.$$formSubmit.trigger('click'); // reference the button and click it
        });
    }
});
```

}

**Here is the Home Controller Code:**

```
private function addsales($payment_type = null, $cash_tendered = null, $cust_name = null, $amt_owed = null) {
    if (isset($payment_type, $cash_tendered)) {
        $email = $_SESSION[DbStrings::$EMAIL];
        $payment_type = $this->test_input($payment_type);
        $cash_tendered = $this->test_input($cash_tendered);


        $insertedSale = $this->member->insertDailySale($email, $payment_type, $cash_tendered);
        $cust_name = $this->test_input($cust_name);
        $amt_owed = $this->test_input($amt_owed);
        $insertedCredit = 1;
        if (isset($cust_name, $amt_owed) && $amt_owed > 0) {
            $insertedCredit = $this->member->insertCredit($email, $cust_name, $amt_owed);
        }

        if ($insertedSale && $insertedCredit) {

            $_SESSION['temp_invoice'] = $_SESSION[DbStrings::$INVOICE];

            $chars = "003232303232023232023456789";
            srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
            $i = 0;
            $pass = '';
            while ($i <= 7) {

                $num = rand() % 33;

                $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);

                $pass = $pass . $tmp;

                $i++;
            }


            $alpha = 'NM-' . $pass;
            $_SESSION[DbStrings::$INVOICE] = $alpha;
            echo "Your sale has been inserted succesfully";
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem inserting your sale. Please try again.";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please fill all fields';
    }
}
```

**And Here is my Model Code that still fetches other functions:**

```
public function insertDailySale($email, $payment_type, $cash_tendered) {

    $invoice = $_SESSION[DbStrings::$INVOICE];
    $this->db->from(DbStrings::$SALES_ORDER_TABLE_NAME);
    $condition = array(DbStrings::$EMAIL => $email, DbStrings::$INVOICE => $invoice);
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $checks = $query->result_array();

    foreach ($checks as $queries) {
        $productID = $queries[DbStrings::$PRODUCTID];
        $quantity = $queries[DbStrings::$SALES_QUANTITY];
        $amount = $queries[DbStrings::$SALES_AMOUNT];
        $profit = $queries[DbStrings::$SALES_PROFIT];
        $product_code = $queries[DbStrings::$PRODUCT_CODE];
        $product_name = $queries[DbStrings::$PRODUCT_NAME];
        $product_selling = $queries[DbStrings::$PRODUCT_SELLING];

        $this->deductInventory($email, $product_code, $quantity);
        $this->updateQuantitySold($email, $product_code, $quantity);
        $cost_price = $this->product->getCostPrice($product_code);

        $data[] = array(
            DbStrings::$EMAIL => $email,
            DbStrings::$INVOICE => $invoice,
            DbStrings::$PRODUCTID => $productID,
            DbStrings::$SALES_QUANTITY => $quantity,
            DbStrings::$SALES_AMOUNT => $amount,
            DbStrings::$SALES_PROFIT => $profit,
            DbStrings::$PRODUCT_CODE => $product_code,
            DbStrings::$PRODUCT_NAME => $product_name,
            DbStrings::$PRODUCT_CP => $cost_price,
            DbStrings::$PRODUCT_SP => $product_selling,
            DbStrings::$PAYMENT_TYPE => $payment_type,
            DbStrings::$CASH_TENDERED => $cash_tendered,
            DbStrings::$DATE_CREATED => time()
        );
        $inserted = $this->db->insert_batch(DbStrings::$DAILYSALES_TABLE_NAME, $data);
    }

    return $inserted;
}
```

With the above, i get flagged this error:

> There was a problem inserting your sale. Please try again.

Please I need help on this.

Comment: The error you posted isn't in your code, but it seems to be a custom made error. It it isn't, could you try to find a stack trace? There's so much code in your question that I don't really know where to look.

Comment: According to you code the error is in `if ($insertedSale && $insertedCredit) {`. You do `$insertedCredit = 1;` so the error should be in `$insertedSale` so 3 possibilities : `if (isset($cust_name, $amt_owed) && $amt_owed > 0) {` is false OR `$insertedCredit = $this->member->insertCredit($email, $cust_name, $amt_owed);` return false/null OR `$insertedSale = $this->member->insertDailySale($email, $payment_type, $cash_tendered);` return false/null

Comment: Thank you @MickaelLeger for the hint. The error is from `insertedSale`, but I don't know why the function `insertDailySale()` is flagging an error.

Comment: @Loek The error is a syntax error i believe, but I don't know where i went wrong in my Model `insertDailySale()`

Comment: The flagged error is your message in `addSale()`, not in `insertDailySale()`, no?

Comment: @MickaelLeger, the flagged error is from `insertDailySale()`. It returns a null value, which is maybe my `foreach loop` isn't doing justice for me. What else can i do, to have a successful insertion with the `foreach loop`?

Comment: Add some `var_dump()` in your foreach to see where you don't get the right value :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger Using the var_dump(), i noticed no value is lost from the foreach loop. But the insertion to database is now the issue.

Comment: @OtoroWonimideiAntonedei If you are 100% sure that you have the right data at the right place, did you tried to add your request "by hand" in the database to see if it return an error? Is your database connection ok?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thanks... the error was from my database table. I removed a column and was still sending data to the removed column.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from my database structure. Being an `internal server error`, it came from the DB.

I realized i deleted a column from my database table, and i was still sending data to the removed column.

Thanks guys for the attempt to help.